# Why does my program that spawns threads that iterate over MPSC channels never exit?

Tags: rust

I made the following program:

```rust
use std::process;
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    let t1 = thread::spawn(move || {
        for i in 0..10 {
            if i != 9 {
                let msg = i32::from(i);
                tx.send(msg).unwrap();
            } else {
                println!("Greetings from process {} of 10!", i);
                for received in rx.iter().take(10) {
                    println!("Greetings from process {} of 10!", received);
                    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
                }
                process::exit(1);
            }
        }
    });
    t1.join().unwrap();
}
```

The program never ends; it executes all the code but it never finalizes. Can someone give me some help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that [`iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.iter) on a [`Receiver`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html) is a blocking call. So since the [`Sender`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Sender.html) didn't "hang up" yet, then it will remain blocked, as you only ever send `9` messages. If you attempt to `take()` `9` or less (i.e. at most what is sent), then the for loop will end as expected.

Alternatively, you can either (1) use [`try_iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.try_iter), which will stop the iteration when there are no more pending values, or (2) you'd need to "hang up" the [`Sender`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Sender.html) prior to entering the for loop, which you can do by calling `drop(tx)`.

```rust
} else {
    drop(tx);
//  ^^^^^^^^
    println!("Greetings from process {} of 10!", i);
    for received in rx.iter().take(10) {
        println!("Greetings from process {} of 10!", received);
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
    }
    process::exit(1);
}
```

or

```rust
} else {
    println!("Greetings from process {} of 10!", i);
    for received in rx.try_iter().take(10) {
//                     ^^^^^^^^
        println!("Greetings from process {} of 10!", received);
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
    }
    process::exit(1);
}
```

*This is of course, ignoring the fact that what you're trying to do, is somewhat confusing, as in why a thread is sending/receiving to itself. However, this will solve the "does not exit" issue.*